# IF vs IIF and performance difference?

Tags: performance, tableau-api

I was wondering what is the difference between the `IF` statement vs the `IIF()` function in Tableau.  And then I found this page, which explained the syntax difference.

[Difference between iif and if](http://tableautips.net/calcs/2014/03/12/iif_or_if.html)

But someone (over a seminar) also told me that `IIF()` has better performance.  Is that true?

Comment: Just [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and find out.

Comment: I tried with a data set with 3.6M rows (an CSV file with about 300MB).  The two different methods both performed very fast.  I don't know enough about how to take detailed measurements.  I tend to think in terms of performance, the two methods are not much different.  The key difference, it seems to me, rather, is that one is a statement and the other is a function.

Comment: Tableau has a built in performance monitor under the Help menu. That will help you get started in gathering performance metrics between using the two functions.

Comment: Looks like you found a pretty good answer. I think the key is to find out, how either function/statement performs on *your data* and with your specific query vs. blanket statements *"x performs better than y"*. If said someone from the seminar had told me, I'd had asked if he had any tests to back this.

Comment: If you look at the performance monitor, check out the SQL that gets generated. I bet it is the same in each case. Points out one thing, any answer is dependent on which database driver you are using (and which version of Tableau and the driver also). The driver converts Tableau commands (VizQL) into specific SQL to send to a specific database.

Comment: @Filburt is right on about demanding to see evidence. For years, programmers insisted that the prefix ++ operator was faster that the postfix ++ operator. That was true with an optimized version of the C programming language -- but usually not relevant. However, the statement persisted as a myth for years with other programming languages even when it no longer held. So look for yourself at the SQL

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.  I have provided an answer to this question myself.  Please see if you agree with me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Statement *vs.* Function**

The key difference between `IF` and `IIF` is that the former is 
a statement

```
IF test THEN value END 
IF test THEN value ELSE else END
```

And the latter is a function

```
IIF(test, then, else, [unknown])
```

Another difference, as has been alluded to in the [cited link
in the opening question](http://tableautips.net/calcs/2014/03/12/iif_or_if.html), is that the latter also supports the 
notion of a seperate handing for the "unknown" case.
Here is [the documentation from Tableau](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_logical.html#two)

> IIF(test, then, else, [unknown])
>
> . . .
>
> A boolean comparison may also yield the value UNKNOWN (neither TRUE
>   nor FALSE), usually due to the presence of Null values in test. The
>   final argument to IIF is returned in the event of an UNKNOWN result
>   for the comparison. If this argument is left out, Null is returned.

In the `IF` statement, the handling of the unknown case is lumped into the `ELSE` block.  From the same document
from Tableau cited above

> The IF THEN ELSE function evaluates a sequence of test conditions and
>   returns the value for the first condition that is true.  If no condition is true, the ELSE value is returned.

**About the Claim About Performance Difference**

As for the claim about the performance difference between the two constructs,
I investigated on the claim:

1. I have conducted quite some search, and I could not found evidence support that claim, either officially by Tableau or by another users.
2. I conducted a small (anecdotal) experiment and I could not observe any performance
   difference (my test involved a dataset of 300MB from a CSV file and has
   3.6M rows in it, both methods performed about as fast as each other).
3. The Tableau employee that told me about the claim seemed to have back-peddled after
    I asked her the same question again for confirmation.

So I would classify the claim to be unsubstantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference:
IF(Condition, "truevalue", IIF(Condition,"truevalue","falsevalue")) - This statement if it see null value will return "falsevalue".

IIF(Condition, "truevalue", IIF(Condition,"truevalue","falsevalue"), "no value") - This function will see null value and return "no value".